# AS3: Loading Facebook profile pictures, can't load certain images

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

As the title says im trying to load Facebook profile images into flash using AS3,
now im pretty far with this but i hit a blockade.

for some reason this id will load:
id: 522015860
url: https://graph.facebook.com/522015860/picture

and this id doesnt load:
id: 100001202215171
url: https://graph.facebook.com/100001202215171/picture

Now notice the "10000" in front of the last one, every id that has this 10000 in front
of it, i am unable to load.

Code Example:

```
private function LoadFacebookImage(id:int):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, FacebookImageLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture"));
}
```

More info:
Im obtaining the friends list of the current user through some PHP a friend of mine wrote, and accesing their ID's, which i use to load their profile images.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Kind regards,
Marco Pisanu

Comment: How are you storing the ID's? A int may not be able to fit that big of a number.

Comment: can you provide some code on how you are loading the current profile images? Are these always the same profile pictures or do you want them to be of the current logged in user? are you using an access_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How are you storing the ID's? A int may not be able to fit that big of a number. – by grapefrukt"

You are totaly correct, the ID was to large for an int.